# iText 7 - How to fill a canvas rectangle with a transparent color

Tags: itext7

In iText 7.1.9 I am taking a pdf created programmatically (not via iText) and need to apply a transparent rectangle along the left side and bottom to ensure the no content exists within a predefined clear zone (for print).

The below code places the yellow rectangles correctly but the desired result is the for the yellow fill to be semi-transparent or not 100% opaque so that visual inspection will show the content that that intersects with the rectangle instead of the rectangle clipping the content.

```
var page = pdf.GetPage(1); 
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.SaveState();                
canvas.SetFillColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.YELLOW);

var pageHeight = page.GetPageSize().GetHeight();
var pageWidth = page.GetPageSize().GetWidth();
// left side
canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, 15, pageHeight);
// bottom
canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, pageWidth, 15);
canvas.Fill();                
canvas.RestoreState();
```

I attempted to use a TransparentColor but canvas.SetFillColor won't accept a TransparentColor, are there any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we speak about low-level content stream instructions, color itself and transparency levels are specified separately in PDF syntax. The `TransparentColor` class that you speak about was designed to simplify lives of users who are less familiar with nuances of PDF syntax, but it it a higher-level class that you can use e.g. in `layout` module, and in your case you operate with the document on quite low level.

Long story short, to set color transparency you only need one additional line next to setting the color itself:

```
canvas.SetExtGState(new PdfExtGState().SetFillOpacity(0.5f));
```

So the code becomes:

```
var page = pdf.GetPage(1); 
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.SaveState();                
canvas.SetFillColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.YELLOW);
canvas.SetExtGState(new PdfExtGState().SetFillOpacity(0.5f));

var pageHeight = page.GetPageSize().GetHeight();
var pageWidth = page.GetPageSize().GetWidth();
// left side
canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, 15, pageHeight);
// bottom
canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, pageWidth, 15);
canvas.Fill();                
canvas.RestoreState();
```